# Каким алгоритмом узнать через сколько секунд часовая и минутная стрелки совместятся?

Tags: алгоритм, delphi, pascal

Программу написать скорее всего смогу, но сам принцип решения мне немного не понятен.

Время, которое показывают часы, задано в часах, минутах и секундах. Определите, через сколько секунд часовая и минутная стрелки совместятся.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Угловая скорость минутной стрелки - 0.1 градус/сек, часовой - (0.1/12) градус/сек. Угол (по часовой стрелке) между минутной и часовой стрелками зависит от их положения, то есть от заданного времени.

Разделите этот угол на разницу угловых скоростей.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ncUHZSS

Такая программа получилась, но она работает не для всех значений-допустим для 6ч 30мин 5 сек она работает неправильно.Как решить?

Comment: @limu не темните. Что значит неправильно? Какое значение должно быть, и какое значение получается?

Comment: 158.6(что неправильно),т.к. при 6.30.5, в то время как при 6.0.0 ответ-1963.6,правильный
@Igor

Comment: @Pa78 Какое значение должно быть, и какое значение получается?

Comment: Правильного значения я не знаю, это по идее должна была программа подсчитывать, но вроде правильное значение около 2100

Comment: @Pa78 "2100" - Откуда взялось это число?

Comment: я добавил еще один If, который прибавлял к углу между часовой и минутной стрелками 360, тогда получилось значение около 2100 сек, в то время как 6 ч 0м 0с дало значение около 3000, следовательно сделано неверно, но преподаватель сказал что первое значение хоть и неправильно, но более менее близко, т.е без изменений программа работает лишь наполовину

Comment: Т.е программа видимо делала все через больший угол, если он превышал 180 у минутной стрелки, и мне, как я понял нужно ввести ограничение через If, но как-не понимаю

Comment: Стрелки совпадут примерно в 6.33, так что 158 сек ~ 2.5 минуты  - это правильно.

Comment: @Pa78 Вы должны быть способны для любого заданного времени посчитать ответ вручную и доказать Вашему преподавателю, что он неправ. Как это сделать - написано выше.

Comment: Да, я уже все понял, ответ сходился с тем, что было написано программой, но тк преподаватель сказал что неверно- я пытался найти другие пути, видимо он что-либо не понял в моей программе, спасибо за ответы.